# How to combine multiple models together?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, pytorch

I am trying to "parallelize" Neural Network models to speed up training. One idea I had was to run two models on two computers and combine the results somehow.

Is this possible? If not, what are the options to parallelize model training on two computers?

I am open to use any neural network framework.

Comment: Are the two models the same model?

Comment: @Daniel Correct, the architecture would be the same

Comment: And you want them to share the same weights and both be updated as one?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean distributed tensorflow?

See official document: https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed